# Slick slider "position: fixed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and trying to position the slider at the bottom of the page.

I'm using `position:fixed` but it simply breaks the slider, meaning every movement causes each cell to grow, double in size I think.

Is there a workaround for this?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="cappa__holder">
    <div class="cappa">111</div>
    <div class="cappa">222</div>
    <div class="cappa">333</div>
    <div class="cappa">444</div>
    <div class="cappa">555</div>
    <div class="cappa">666</div>
    <div class="cappa">777</div>
</div>

.cappa__holder {
    /* uncomment next line to see it break */
    //position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;
}

.cappa {
    text-align: center;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    margin: 4px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cappa__holder').slick({
      infinite: true,
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      speed: 600
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/3893s80b/4/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem: when `.cappa__holder` has `position:fixed;` and does not have height, the slick can not calculate the size of slides. However, you only need to give width to the `.cappa__holder` to solve your problem(for example `width:100%`).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3893s80b/5/)